# Keyboard shortcut for end of line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've been searching the other posts for an answer to this but they all have been slightly different than what I am looking for.

I am used to developing in OS X where the simple keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> goes to the end of line.

Is there a way to wire up this command on Ubuntu? I have a Mac Book with Ubuntu so I don't have an End key.

I've tried the Custom Shortcuts in the Keyboard settings but can't get the command to work for end of line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Install `xdotool` : `sudo apt-get install xdotool`
2. Go to system connections -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> custom
3. Create new shortcut, binding `bash -c "xdotool getactivewindow key End"` command to some key combination

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! For a bonus, how could I do command shift right arrow to highlight to end of line?

Comment: @tyelford sorry , i don't have a mac, what's the command +shift + right-arrow does ?

Comment: I am trying to highlight all text to the end of the line.

Comment: Ah . . .  well , same idea, make a shortcut for it , but use `xdotool getactivewindow key Shift+End` as a comman. Also . . .try to get out of the  Mac mode of thinking - there's no command key on Ubuntu. There is super key, which acts more like Window's key

Comment: Thank you again, I nearly had it but forgot the plus between the Shift and End.  Yes I know the super key is like the windows key but that particular shortcut is so handy because my left thumb is can reach the super key perfectly.

Comment: This is so true. I'm sorely missing Ctrl-A and Ctrl-E for Home and End. The home and end keys on a PC keyboard are placed too far away. You want these shortcuts immediately available whilst your typing code.

Comment: I found that xdotool was too slow to use as a shortcut for Home and End. I had to add a [keyup command](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/210) and then run the command to run Home. I ended up using AutoKey which works flawlessly. The method is described [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-map-home-end-pgdown-and-pgup-if-these-keys-dont-exist-in-my-keyboard/36789/10)

Answer (score 11):

On a Mac keyboard (running Ubuntu), the

```
function (fn) key + left/right arrow
```

key seems to be equivalent to the

```
command +left/right arrow
```

functionality seen native Mac environment.

Comment: Thanks! worked on my MacBook Pro running Lubuntu

Comment: That also worked on my Dell Inspiron keyboard running Ubuntu.

Comment: Worked on RedHat accessed remotely using a Macbook Pro

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a mac keyboard, simply use **function+left** for **home** and **function+right** to **end** of the line. We don't need to install any other software.

Answer (score 0):

On my keyboard (msi),
`function (fn) key + left/right arrow` is used for changing the volume
`function (fn) key + Page Up/Page down (⇟/⇞)` gets me to the beginning/end of line respec.