# Why do "fn ->" and "fn <-" behavior differently on T470 & T480?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lenovo

I have a T480 and a T470, both running Ubuntu 18.04. On the T480 "<kbd>Fn</kbd> ->" and "<kbd>Fn</kbd> <-" move the cursor to the end and beginning of the line. On the T470 that combination does nothing, I have to reach up to the Home and End keys. I can't seem to create any custom key combinations with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at all on the T470. I've tried using xdotool [as suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/753322/530103) with no luck as the custom key binding interface doesn't recognize I am pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.

What's the difference, and is there any way to align the T470's behavior with the T480?